# Entering excel formula with quotations in a loop using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use VBA to to insert a formula in excel that would look like the following in excel:

```
=BDH(C2,"PX LAST",F2,"","Dir=H","days=w","DTS=H","cols=1;rows=1")
```

This actually represents just the first row of this formula, which I want to be copied down a certain column. Therefore I have to use a loop with index `i` and then reference the appropriate cells with Cells notation, i.e. `C2=Cells(i,3)` and `F2=Cells(i,6)`. After looking through some discussions on this site and others, I know that in order to create a literal quote within a string, you use a double quote (`""`).

```vb
formulaString = "=BDH(Cells" & CStr(i) & ",3),""PX LAST"",Cells(" & CStr(i) & ",6),"""",""Dir=H"",""days=w"",""DTS=H"",""cols=1;rows=1"")"
```

I want to insert these formulas in the 8th column of the corresponding row, so I do this with

```
Cells(i,8).Formula = formulaString
```

However, when I do this I get the error "application defined or object-defined error". I also saw that this can similarly be done with the code

```
Cells(i,8).Value = Evaluate(formulaString)
```

This does not throw an error, but when it runs the cells in which I want the formula read `#Value`.

Could someone please help me identify what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be putting the `Cells` inside the formula string, and you should be using the `Address` property:

```
formulaString = "=BDH(" & Cells(i,3).Address(False, False) & ",""PX LAST""," & Cells(i,6).Address(False, False) & ","""",""Dir=H"",""days=w"",""DTS=H"",""cols=1;rows=1"")"
```

However what you actually want is [switching to the R1C1 notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21689949/11683):

```
formulaStringR1C1 = "=BDH(RC3,""PX LAST"",RC6,"""",""Dir=H"",""days=w"",""DTS=H"",""cols=1;rows=1"")"
```

and then using

```
Cells(i,8).FormulaR1C1 = formulaStringR1C1
```