# VBA : How do I insert VLookup formula (instead of the values) in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting a "database" (that mixes Line of Businesses, Business Units and some other informations) of keys in an excel workbook . 
I need to do a VLookup with these keys and search these keys in another excel workbook. and I want to do this via VBA.

```
Sub CreateVLookUp()
    Dim rw As Long, x As Range
    Dim extwbk As Workbook, twb As Workbook
    Dim KeyRange As Range
    Dim KeyCell As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set KeyRange = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("I8:I" & lastrow)

    Set twb = ThisWorkbook
    Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\vih8452\Documents\ExcelFile.xlsx")
    Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("Database Structure").Range("$A:$T")



    With twb.Sheets("Parameters")

        For rw = 15 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
            .Cells(rw, 14) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 9).Value2, x, 15, False)
            .Cells(rw, 15) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 9).Value2, x, 11, False)
            .Cells(rw, 16) = Application.VLookup(.Cells(rw, 9).Value2, x, 12, False)
        Next rw

    End With

    extwbk.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

I have already almost succeeded in my task, but the main problem is that when I run the VBA macro, it just pastes the result. 
What I want is to see the result in the cell, but also the formula in the formula bar (so I can check whether my result is true or false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the loop when setting the formula:

```
Sub CreateVLookUp()
    Dim x As Range
    Dim extwbk As Workbook
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\vih8452\Documents\ExcelFile.xlsx")
    Set x = extwbk.Worksheets("Database Structure").Range("$A:$T")

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Parameters")

        lastrow = .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(15, 14), .Cells(lastrow, 14)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(I15," & x.Address(1, 1, xlA1, 1) & ",15,FALSE)"
        .Range(.Cells(15, 15), .Cells(lastrow, 15)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(I15," & x.Address(1, 1, xlA1, 1) & ",11,FALSE)"
        .Range(.Cells(15, 16), .Cells(lastrow, 16)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(I15," & x.Address(1, 1, xlA1, 1) & ",12,FALSE)"

    End With
    extwbk.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, it is finally working.
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: A last question to fully understand how this vba code function. How does the VLookup knows in the row 16 by example, it switches the lookup value to I16 and so on ?

Comment: @Orfuz Because internally the formulas are in R1C1 like the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56079204/11683) shows, and in R1C1 all cells in your column have [identical formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55532259/11683). `vlookup` does not do anything to make it happen.

Comment: @Orfuz it acts like a drag fill, as it goes down the column it will change any relative references accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write like this:

```
 .Cells(rw, 14).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(" & .Cells(rw, 9).Value & ", C1:C20, 15, FALSE)"
```

or

```
 .Cells(rw, 14).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5], C1:C20, 15, FALSE)"
```

To refer another sheet just place:

```
 .Cells(rw, 14).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP('Sheet Name'!RC[-5], 'Sheet Name'!C1:C20, 15, FALSE)"
```

Comment: one problem, the lookup range is in a different workbook and sheet.  This will lookup the range on the wrong sheet.

Comment: I am getting a Run-time error '1004': when trying to run your code Pspl

And yes Scott is right, this will not lookup in the right range as the range is in another workbook.

Comment: Finally, show that `rw` and the loop are not needed.

Comment: Still, with the code :
.Cells(rw, 14).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP('Sheet Name'!RC[-5], 'Sheet Name'!C1:C20, 15, FALSE)"
The problem is that I can´t refer to the sheet in the other workbook

Comment: @Orfutz, I don't get why you're getting an error. In any way it has nothing to do with the formula. If it has an error is not a run-time. It's a formula error and display's it on the cell.