# Increment excel column reference using vba? Z to AA, AA to AB

Tags: vba, excel

Required: To refer the column values in a list.

There are n number of rows in one sheet and each cell has a list that is referenced from column values in another sheet. I created the following code but it breaks after Z because the ASCII values are not for AA, AB,...

How to create the list for all the rows using VBA?

```
Sub createList()
'creating custom list referencing cells from another sheet

Sheets("Checklist").Select
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 100

    Dim k As String
    k = "='Parameter Options'!$" & Chr(64 + i) & "$1:$" & Chr(64 + i) & "$10"

    'Parameter Options is the sheet i am taking list values from

    Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Select

    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=k
    End With

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Try using a column number with a function to convert it to a letter -more info here: [Function to convert column number to letter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796973/function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx) with *external:=true* to capture the worksheet name as well as the cell range address. The [Range.Offset property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) staggers your selection as you increment through the loop.

```
Sub createList()
    'don't declare your vars inside a loop!!!
    Dim k As String, i As Long

    For i = 1 To 100

        With Worksheet("Parameter Options")
            k = "=" & .Range("A1:A10").Offset(0, i - 1).Address(external:=True)
            'debug.print k
        End With

        'Parameter Options is the sheet i am taking list values from
        With Worksheets("Checklist").Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=k
        End With

    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

You [don't need column letters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21689949/11683) when working with code.

```
Sub createList()
  'creating custom list referencing cells from another sheet

  Dim i As Long

  For i = 1 To 100
    Dim k As String
    k = "='Parameter Options'!R1C" & i & ":R10C" & i

    With Worksheets("Checklist").Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Validation
      .Delete
      .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Application.ConvertFormula(k, xlR1C1, xlA1)
    End With
  Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Haven't seen the [Application.ConvertFormula Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822751.aspx) for a while. Good use of it here.

Answer (score 4):

Using your code, if you add this modification it will convert double-lettered columns properly, but as noted as in the comment, you are better off using column numbers, more straightforward.

However for a simple quick solution, this will do it:

```
Dim i As Integer

    Dim k As String
    Dim col As String

For i = 1 To 100

    If i < 27 Then
        col = Chr(64 + i)
    Else
        col = Chr(64 + Int(i / 26)) & Chr(64 + i - (Int(i / 26) * 26))
    End If

    k = "='Parameter Options'!$" & col & "$1:$" & col & "$10"

    'Parameter Options is the sheet i am taking list values from

    Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Select

    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=k
    End With

Next i
```

Comment: Should there be a third possibility for triple letter columns?

Comment: @Jeeped - I tested it in Excel2003 and 2 letters are ok, but if that is not the case in higher versions, sure I can add. But per the OP it is 1 to 100 that is up to DD, not more.

Comment: This code works for me, but the issue is with AZ, it is taking as B@, may I know what could the reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution.
I generate a cycle inside another, to handle the values that happen to the Z in code ASCII.

Hope this can help you:

```
For i = 0 To RecordSet.Fields.Count - 1 'This is my data source
    If Ascii > 90 Then
        Ascii = 65
        For y = i To RecordSet.Fields.Count - 1
            Hoja1.Range("A" & Chr(Ascii) & 3).Value = RecordSet.Fields(y).Name
            Ascii = Ascii + 1
        Next
    Else
        Hoja1.Range(Chr(Ascii) & 3).Value = RecordSet.Fields(i).Name
        Ascii = Ascii + 1
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution to find the columnletters also for columns greater than 702 (= three letters) using modulo arithmetics. Note: It doesn't check validity.

**Code**

```
Function colChar(colNo As Long) As String
If colNo < 1 Then Exit Function
Dim n As Long
Dim c As Byte
Dim s As String

n = colNo
Do
    c = ((n - 1) Mod 26)    ' locate within A-Z
    s = Chr(c + 65) & s     ' combine characters
    n = (n - c) \ 26        ' check the rest
Loop While n > 0
colChar = s                 ' return character(s)
End Function
```